# Calculate due date and exclude working/business days SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query, date-arithmetic

I would like to calculate a due date.
If the start date is 30/12/2020, I need to count 20 working days from start date and display the date for the 20th working date from start date.

For example if the start date is 30/12/2020 must give me 28/01/2021 (excludes saturdays and sundays and finds the 20th working day from 30/12/2020).

But I am unable to exclude the weekends.

```
  SELECT 
  DATEADD(DAY,20,CAST(CAST('2020-12-30' AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw,'2020-12-30') = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw,'2020-12-30') = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DueDate
```

thanks

Comment: how about holidays? Is sat and sunday the only days you want excluded?

Comment: Anyway the best solution is to have a date table (dimDate) and have all the properties of that date that you want in there. isWorkDay would be pertinent to you. But other common columns are Week, Month, monthName, Year, FiscalYear etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best pick would be to build a calendar table, with a boolean flag that indicates whether each day is a working day or not. Then you would just do something like:

```
select dt
from calendar
where dt >= '20201231' and is_working_day = 1
order by dt
offset 19 rows fetch next 1 row only
```

The way your question is asked, however, one option enumerates the days in a subquery until the count of working days is reached:

```
declare @dt date = '20201231';
declare @no_days int = 20;

with cte as (
    select @dt as dt, @no_days as no_days
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, dt), 
        case when datename(weekday, dt) in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') 
            then no_days
            else no_days - 1
        end
    from cte
    where no_days > 1
)
select max(dt) as res from cte
```

Comment: Interesting use of calendar table. I would of proposed a row_number() solution.

Comment: thanks, if @dt is a series of dates contained in a table, select dt = (select CustActionDate from #loopCustActiondate), I would like to calculate 20 days for each date in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about holidays, then the 20th working day is exactly 28 days later.  So you can use:

```
dateadd(day, 28, '2020-12-30')
```

Note:  This assumes that the starting date is a working day.